# Flutter: Widget compression priority

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, constraints, flutter-constraint

I'm a beginner in Flutter, and now I try to understand how I can set for layouts of widget compression priority. What I want for example:

I have `Horizontal Stack` like `Row`, it has inside:

Some space like `SizedBox`, then some `Text`. And I want to reduce space before the text when the text is overflowing them self space.

[image]

os ios it resolving by compression priority in layout constraints, but how I can do the same on flutter?

my current code

```
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: titleWidth),
              Expanded(child: subline),
            ],
          )
```

where `titleWidth` is width space, should be applied when `subline` widget smaller than rest accessible size `pinkSpace`.
`subline` is a widget. in the example, it is a `Text`.

but the code works only like on the card with 'But instead this ...' it doesn't reduce space before text widget.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your code but you can use card widget, may it work

Comment: it works ONLY as 'But instead this...' it does not reduce space before text widget

Comment: can you share some code example about your project?

Comment: i already added some code to my question. but it doesn't have any special

Answer (score 0):

### Spacing widgets

Flutter have lots of widgets to help with spacing - inside widgets like `Row` or `Column` that take in a list of children.

#### F.ex:

- `Spacer` - A widget that fills the space between the other children widgets.
- `Flexible` - Wraps a widget and allows you to define a `flex` value to affect how much space this widget should take, compared to the other widgets in the children list.
- `Expanded` - If you wrap a widget in this you make a widget fill up the remaining space.
- `ConstrainedBox` - Allows setting minWidth, maxWidth, minHeight, maxHeight for the child widget.

### Code example

Given your requirement:

1. Have a indent for single line text
2. Don't have a indent for multiline text

#### SizedBox is a no-go

`SizedBox` won't work with multiline text, since multiline `Text` in a `Row` has to be wrapped in `Flexible` ([Flutter - multiline label inside row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55038577/flutter-multiline-label-inside-row)), and the SizedBox would always occupy whatever width you set it to - no combination of Spacer, Flexible, or Expanded seems to work here.

#### Alternative solution

One option is to specify a `Row` with mainAxisAlignment set to `MainAxisAlignment.end` and use a BoxConstraint with a MediaQuery for the screen width subtracted with the minWidth we want for the text container.

- This is effectively the reverse of the SizedBox attempt.

```dart
class IndentedText extends StatelessWidget {
  const IndentedText({Key? key, required this.text, this.textMinWidth = 150}) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final double textMinWidth;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - textMinWidth),
            child: Text(text),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Then the usage of the widget

```dart
class SpacingExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const SpacingExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Card(
          child: Column(
            children: const [
              IndentedText(text: "text"),
              IndentedText(
                text:
                    "A vehicle is a object people use to get around more easily, etc etc make the text longer and multiline.",
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

How it looks:

[image]

- Note: For more complex use-cases when you subtract the minWidth - you might need to also subtract the size of other widgets if the layout if it have multiple Columns f.ex., and possibly the size of padding.

Comment: but i need space before the text if the text doesn't overflow themself

Comment: Edited answer with one solution, a bit rough, but it works 

Comment: Maybe i was not clear, please see my screenshot. i look for behaving like on screenshot except the card with the text 'but instead this...'. on this card I showed current behavior.

Comment: Ahh, so you want it left-aligned to the vehicle icon when it fits and didn't want it multiline, but rather you wanted the ellipsis overflow if it expands outside the entire row? If so try setting the `Text` widget's properties: `maxLines: 1` and `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` in the IndentedText widget I made.

Comment: it is already done, my question is - how to reduce left space in the case when Text overflowing

Answer (score 0):

try this code, I hopefully about this

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Expanded(
           child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(width: titleWidth),
          Expanded(child:Card( child: subline)),
        ],
      )
        
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if get error, try  parent Column wrap with Expanded too